# SQL: How to count items in a specific ordernation

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is my table:

PACKAGE_ID  ITEM_ID

1   1

1   2

1   3

2   4

2   5

3   6

4   7

4   8

I want a new column called count that count 1 to N according to package ID. E.g.:

PACKAGE_ID  ITEM_ID COUNT

1   1   1

1   2   2

1   3   3

2   4   1

2   5   2

3   6   1

4   7   1

4   8   2


Thanks!
p.s: I'm using MariaDb 10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select *, (select count(1) 
           from table t1 
           where t1.PACKAGE_ID = t.PACKAGE_ID and 
                 t1.ITEM_ID <= t.ITEM_ID
           ) as COUNT 
from table t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window function.

```
SELECT PACKAGE_ID, ITEM_ID
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PACKAGE_ID ORDER BY PACKAGE_ID, ITEM_ID) AS THE_COUNT
FROM your_table
```

Comment: You are over killing, just use `ITEM_ID` in `order by` clause.

Comment: Seconding Yogesh, you only need `ITEM_ID` in `ORDER BY` since it is unique to the table.

Comment: It seems perfect! Thank you guys and sorry for bad formatting my question

Answer (score 2):

In pre 8.0 MySQL, the fastest method is probably variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@p = package_id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@p := package_id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as counter
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @p := -1) params
order by package_id, item_id;
```

Obviously an index on `(package_id, item_id)` would benefit this query.

In MySQL 8+ or similar versions of MariaDB, use `row_number()`: